# Error while compiling the Linux kernel 2.6.35

Tags: linux-kernel, compilation

I am trying to compile the Linux kernel on my Ubuntu machine

But I am getting the following error. I've searched on Google but have not been able to find any error related to this.

```
drivers/platform/x86/intel_scu_ipc.c: In function ‘pwr_reg_rdwr’:
drivers/platform/x86/intel_scu_ipc.c:175: error: ‘MRST_CPU_CHIP_PENWELL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
drivers/platform/x86/intel_scu_ipc.c:175: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
drivers/platform/x86/intel_scu_ipc.c:175: error: for each function it appears in.)
drivers/platform/x86/intel_scu_ipc.c: In function ‘intel_scu_ipc_init’:
drivers/platform/x86/intel_scu_ipc.c:741: error: implicit declaration of function ‘mrst_identify_cpu’
make[3]: *** [drivers/platform/x86/intel_scu_ipc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [drivers/platform/x86] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers/platform] Error 2
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

Comment: Do you have the headers package as well as kernel source?

Comment: @sje397: He must have the headers - otherwise there'd be complaints about not finding them.  The trouble appears to be that one of the headers doesn't match the source in this driver.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: you're right. @siri: are you sure you have the *correct* headers package, and any symlinks are correct? I don't mean to imply it *couldn't* be a bug in the source code...but there's a lot that can go wrong building a kernel.

Comment: You are reporting that your error is in 2.6.35, however I cannot find MRST_CPU_CHIP_PENWELL in the entire kernel source. I think that you might be using a variant of 2.6.35. Exactly how did you acquire the source? Git, Tarball?

Comment: @Noah I have acquired the source using git

Comment: Then it is likely not *exactly* 2.6.35 unless you actually checked out the specific tagged version. Look at the first 4 lines in the Makefile located in the root of the kernel tree. Please post those 4 version numbers.

Comment: VERSION = 2
PATCHLEVEL = 6
SUBLEVEL = 35
EXTRAVERSION =  SystemCallTest
NAME = Sheep on Meth

Comment: You should checkout an official 2.6.35 release. `git co v2.6.32` <-- or something close to that. Look at the tags in git to find the exact name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly likely that you are building the kernel with a configuration that has a mistake. It happens occasionally; there are hundreds of configuration options, and they can't all be checked.

The first thing you want to do is confirm that you are able to build at least *some* configuration. So, just build a default configuration. This is primarily to rule out operator error:

```
make distclean
make defconfig
make
```

If that fails there may be problems with your setup / environment. Try an older kernel, and report back here. If you are able to build the default configuration then you should report the failed configuration to the Linux Kernel Mailing List

- http://www.lkml.org

From there they will be able to help you, tell you to wait, or direct you to a subsystem maintainer for the failed driver.